# pipenv python variables to php

Tags: python, php

So I have this `pipenv` where I have a  log of variables in python that I would like to have transferred over to my 'PHP.'

My terminal commandos for running this python is:

```
pipenv shell
py pyget/jira.py
--OUTMPUTS VARIABLES--
```

The python code is:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    jira = Jira()

    fields = jira.get_fields()
    jql_issues = jira.get_jql_search_issues(jql_search="project = SWA")
    for issue in jql_issues:
        logging.info(f"Key: {issue.key} - Assignee: {issue.fields.assignee.display_name}")
```

I need to get the variables `issue.key` and `issue.fields.assignee.display_name` over  to PHP.

I found an example of how it can be done, but I don't quite get it since I've never done this before.

This is what I've found:

php code:

```php
<?php
$state = $argv[1];
echo $state;
?>
```

python code:

```py
from subprocess import *
#ledstate='on'
p = Popen(['/usr/bin/php','<php file name>',ledstate],stdout=PIPE)
print p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the variable contents (e.g. `issue.key`)? Are these confidential items of data that need to be kept private? One option is to get Python to write them to a file and then read that in using PHP. But it depends on the nature of the data as to whether that's advisable.

Comment: `jql_issues` contains an array of strings like `issue.key`, so I just loop trough and get all the strings `issue.key and issue.fields.assignee.display_name` which can be somthing like `issue.key = "SWA-123"`